# API do Buscapé parou de retornar XML

Tags: xml, api, aplicação-web, request

Eu estou tentando acessar o endereço http://sandbox.buscape.com.br/service/findProductList/554163674d2f57624d676f3d/BR/?categoryId=77&keyword=Samsung pelo navegador mas parou de retornar o XML. A aplicação parou de retornar uns dias atrás, ela retornava certo o XML tanto na aplicação quanto direto no navegador mas de uns dias para cá parou de retornar tudo, em qualquer navegador e na aplicação onde utilizo, estou no ambiente de desenvolvimento ainda onde preciso passar o nome sandbox conforme endereço web. Alguém sabe o que pode ter ocorrido?

Comment: Se antes funcionava e você não alterou nada, não seria melhor entrar em contato com o pessoal do Buscape?

Comment: Estou tentando mas pessoal la não responde nada ainda.